# Hosting Website Issue

Tags: hosting, iis-6, asp.net, web-hosting, windows

I have a web project which I want to post in to our company`s hosting server: IIS Vs.6.0. The name of the server which is running our whole websites is: **testing.test.com** and domain is **testing.com** I am added as a User in it as myname@testing.com.

Now in the IIS Manager in the server there is a folder called websites and I made a folder called 'test'. Published my project into that folder. But here is the catch:

I am logging in my PC as another domain and the server is in another domain. When I see the permissions of this folder it says:

**myname@testing.com**

However, I am accessing this webpage as: **myname@anotherdomain.com**. This err I am getting when accessing the page:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Login failed for user
>   'testing\test'.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Login failed for user
>   'testing\test'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'testing\test'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +183
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +43
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +47
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +20
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +34
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create(DataContext context, IEnumerable`1 sequence) +82
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.GetNewBindingList() +40
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList() +15
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(Object dataSource, String dataMember) +54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ReadOnlyDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String viewName) +41
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView() +266
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.GetData() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +59
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   EntityRegistration.FrontEnd.AgentList.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\raj.OIS\Desktop\Dropbox\OIS Entity\EntityRegistration\EntityRegistration\FrontEnd\AgentList.aspx.cs:35
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The biggest clue is in the stack trace: `[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'E-SOFTIND\MAGNUS$'.]` You need to fix your permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using integrated security for your SQL Server connection string. If that is the case, you will need to add the Network Service or E-SOFTIND\$MAGNUS login to the SQL Server in question. That new login should be a Windows user and mapped to the database in question with appropriate rights to read/write/delete/etc. as needed in the database.

If SQL Server is installed on the same computer as the web server, use the local Network Service account. If it is on a different computer within the same domain, use E-SOFTIND\$MAGNUS as the Windows user (this is a map to the Network Service account on the MAGNUS computer, on the E-SOFTIND domain).

Note the user name is the domain, a back-slash ("\"), the dollar sign ("$"), then the name of the computer the web server is installed to.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear where your database is residing here, I'm going to presume on the web server.

The issue is your Sql configuration is using the default windows integrated authentication method running in the context of your web app (E-SOFTIND\MAGNUS$) and said user isn't setup on the SQL instance on your database server so the credentials are getting rejected.

Very easy to fix, typical options include:

- Add the `E-SOFTIND\MAGNUS$` user to the sql instance, give it appropriate permissions (`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo` is a good 1st guess if you have no idea).
- Change the application pool to use a defined user account then grant that user appropriate SQL permissions.
- Change authentication methods entirely to use SQL authentication. Create sql user, grant appropriate permissions, then change connection string in web.config to use new named sql user.

But, basically, you need to identify a user and give it appropriate permissions in your database.

Comment: My DB is in another server. Not in the same server..

Comment: So technically my DB is in the another server and hosting webpages is in the another...

Comment: Ok, best bet then would be to use SQL authentication since you probably don't have enough access in enough places to do windows auth. Another reasonable thing would be to ask the hosting provider what the recommend.